# Confirm a photo was taken by an authorised person

Tags: mobile

The company I work for hires realtors to go and inspect properties, including taking pictures of.  We need to make sure that the realtor is the one taking the picture, and is not sending some else to do it.

So far, the only way that comes to mind is seeing the phone the pictures were taken with and double check that number with the realtor's phone number on record.

Comment: The photo app including the camera model in the EXIF info I can understand, but I would not expect it to include serial number. The camera app doesn't know the "phone number" associated with the SIM, of course. The camera will work fine if no SIM is inserted. Cameras which are not phones still exist.

Comment: There are apps which claim to fulfill this need.  These apps are usually marketed to vendors to prove they did a job at a specified place and time.  I can't vouch for any in particular.

Comment: The most obvious solution is to ask for a selfie as one of the pics? Check the timestamps on the selfie and the expected photos, if there is a concern.

Comment: It seems to me more like a people problem than a technical problem. If you say "If you send someone else to do your job for you, there will be repercussions!". I'm sure this would deter many from doing so. Then again, why is it a problem for you if they send someone else? If all you care is that pictures are taken, then why does it matter who takes them?

Answer (score 1):

The one thing you have to be careful with is placing too many restrictions on the person taking the photo.

- What if the person wants to use their own camera (not a phone)?
- What if the person has a disability that makes it difficult to take clear pictures? My hands shake and if I was hired to take pictures, I'd bring my kid or a friend with me to actually take the photos.

You could use or develop an app that requires authentication or that gathers data about the device, but then people can easily get around that, too. I could get a burner phone, register that with your company, install the app on that, and hand that (or ship it) to someone else to go to the property.

This is not a technology problem that you have because you want to verify the *person* took the photos, not that a particular *device* took the photos. And the people problem is a far easier problem to solve.

***Get the person to take a selfie at the property that includes the sky.***

The sky is important because it helps to confirm that the selfie and the property photos were taken at roughly the same time/day. You can also check the timestamps on the photos, although this can be edited.

This way, the person is free to take the photos however they wish, but they have to be physically present around the time the rest of the photos were taken. The realtor could still hire someone else to do everything, but now it is no longer convenient to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata attached to photos taking with the default camera on a mobile device contain information such as the date, camera's general information, camera settings and location.  This information is stored in EXIF format as part of the file.  **In general the default camera app will not accomplish what you want.**

**It is possible to create custom EXIF tags and inject them in to an image** such as Tag 37500 (page 27 of the [EXIF2 documentation](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF)) which can be any thing you would like.

> A tag for manufacturers of Exif writers to record any desired information. The contents are up to the manufacturer, but this tag should not be used for any other than its intended purpose.
>
> - Tag = 37500 (927C.H)
> - Type = UNDEFINED
> - Count = Any
> - Default = none

**If you are comfortable forcing them to use "your" app instead of the default camera app you could read the phone number and put it in there.**

As others have suggested there may be apps already that do something similar to this, but I don't know of one specifically and the "how" of it would change depending on if you were targeting iOS or Android.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? What's stopping anyone from faking such an EXIF tag?

Comment: I don't mean to sound condescending, but I figured editing Exif is beyond the average realtor's skill set.  Moreover, the extra effort involved in doing so would still work toward dissuading them from attempting to circumvent the process.  Your point is valid though, if you wanted to be more sure, record their device ID and sign them digitally, but I was going for an easier approach since I figured they weren't programmers or IT experts.  Moreover, as much as "security through obscurity" isn't a valid tactic, if you don't tell them what you are doing it's a lot harder to work around.

Comment: Sign them digitally with what key?

Comment: Any key one wants since the users aren't likely to (know how to) decompile the app to find it.   Both iOS and Android have built in libraries for this even providing secure storage.  If one is extra worried, one could set up a service in the cloud to upload whatever you want to in order to sign it.  At that point why not just upload the photos themselves though.  I wasn't trying to suggest anything terribly complex, rather I was aiming at something most people wouldn't bother to circumvent.